# What is the best way to display a form with OneToMany fields?

Tags: forms

Imagine a form that asks the user to create his blog. This form asks for the name, description and some others info about his blog. Then, the user can select 0:n people he wants to manage his blog.

I'm stuck on how to "design" this integration:

- Should I show a one-page form, containing all the fields and an "Add" button that would add a new line for the user to add people
- or should I do a many-steps form, first with all the basic fields, and then showing the blog details and an "Add people" button that would show a single form?

The advantage of the first point is that everything is made at one time, but it requires javascript to work.
The second way can ignore javascript but forces the user to click many times.

What would you do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen a pattern similar to this, it might be on facebook for preferences maybe, the idea goes something like this:

1. Present the 1:M name
2. Present a single row for input
3. Use javascript to add a new row when the last row has received text

Then save it all at the end, or do it with javascript behind the scenes.

Multistep forms seem painful.

The first method works best with javascript enabled, sure, but you could do something like have 3 or 4 blanks provided and hide all but one if javascript is enabled.  That way even without javascript the user can enter 3 or 4 at one time.

Comment: Especially since the information about the blog seems minimal (less than 10 fields).